# How to enable Gold linker?

Tags: android-ndk, linker, gold-linker

I recall that when Gold linker was introduced to NDK, there was an instruction on how to switch to it. But now I can't find that info anywhere in the docs. So, what do I put to my `Application.mk` in order to use the `gold` linker?

I've tried this flag:
`APP_LDFLAGS += -fuse-ld=gold --threads`

and it throws this error:

> arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option --threads'

so I suspect this is not `gold` I'm linking with.

Answer (score 2):

The gold linker is the default for ARM (and x86). From the [Revision 8c release notes](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html):

> Added Gold linker ld.gold for the Windows toolchain. **Gold linker is
>   also the default for ARM and X86 on all hosts.** You may override it to
>   use the ld.bfd linker by adding LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fuse-ld=bfd to
>   Android.mk, or by passing -fuse-ld=bfd to the g++/clang++ command line
>   that does the linking.

It looks like your error message comes from the C++ compiler, not the linker. If the linker is being invoked via the compiler then you could try passing linker args with `-Wl,--threads`. Otherwise, perhaps you also have `--threads` specified somewhere else.

Comment: I've just added the `--threads` flag - it's the new `gold` feature, multi-threaded linking. Should be extremely useful given that my app compiles in 3 minutes but takes another 4 to link with LTO. `-Wl` will probably solve it!